# Grails upgrade from 2.2.3 to 2.5.1

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

The project I've been working on needs to upgrade it's grails version from  2.2.3 to 2.5.1. Needless to say, the project is huge and I am sure there will be lots of issues while upgrading.

What are the precautions needed while upgrading? And what are the changes required in the dependencies below:

```
dependencies {
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
        compile ('ar.com.fdvs:DynamicJasper:5.0.0')
        compile ('org.apache.poi:poi:3.10-FINAL')
        compile ("com.aspose:aspose-words:14.5.0")
        compile ("com.aspose:aspose-cells:8.4.2")
    }
```

As well as in plugins below:

```
plugins {
        compile ":aws-sdk:1.6.7"
        compile ":export:1.5"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the high level changes listed for each major release up to 2.5.0 in the [2.5.1 documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.1/guide/introduction.html).

You will need to note all of the features which will change during the upgrade, identify where you are using them and plan how you are going to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when upgrading the Grails version (apart from reading the upgrade sections of the version I'm upgrading to and all in between major versions) is create a new empty application with the new Grails.
And then use a tree compare tool (like `meld`) and compare all the build and configuration files to see what has changed.

This way you get most of the needed changes without much trouble. You still need to test your application thoroughly. Hopefully you have lots of unit and integration tests to help you with that...